# Render blocking and CSS

Tags: css, styles, rendering, google-pagespeed, render-blocking

I imagine this has been asked time and time again, but i've not seen the answer I'm looking for.

Im doing some simple tests with a HTML file and CSS file trying to stop the page from render blocking the CSS, running the site through page insights ( google )

Now i've seen answers like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.20180530.css?ver=1.0" media="none" onload="if(media!='all')media='all'">
```

and I've seen answers like this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,700" rel="preload" onload="this.rel='stylesheet';this.removeAttribute('onload');" as="style">
```

Both of which I am fine with, for the google fonts! But not for the main styles of the page, I don't think its a good user experience to see a page with no styles and then all of a sudden they load in.

Obviously you can eliminate any blocking of CSS by sticking the whole lot as inline styles, but again I don't think this is good practice, you're outputting all styles to a HTML page and not loading them via a style sheet.

I've seen sites actually load the styles like so:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='main-css'  href='./style.2018052108.css?ver=4.9' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

[Heres](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.clicky.co.uk%2F) a link to the page insight speed test on the. I know the site is running wordpress. If you view page source it uses the exact same as i've used above.

And they aren't Render Blocking at all... **How?**

Im on a https I'm using cloudflare and my style sheet is compressed and only around **24bytes** and I'm still getting render blocking.

1. **Why?**
2. How to avoid it?

Comment: You will always get render blocking but it's not an issue at all ... these are simple recommendation and you can never follow all them. And you will never never obtain a score of 100% .. you need to focus on the page speed/load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS loaded as an external request is always render blocking, you can't avoid it. The recommendation on pagespeed insights is that you don't do any css request before the content is loaded, in order to avoid the unstyled effect they suggest that you inline the CSS needed to display the content before the fold.

The page on your example is doing exactly that, they inline some css content (check the source code and search for the `style` tag), then, when the content is loaded they add an external stylesheet with javascript.

All that said, this is a recommendation, you can ignore it if you are happy with the performance of your page, if you want to follow the recommendation you can apply some techniques to achieve this in an automation way.

As always, in css-tricks you have a great introduction post to these techniques: https://css-tricks.com/authoring-critical-fold-css/

Comment: No I don't think you're right there. There isn't any css in the source that would do any styles for above the fold content. The only **style** tag i can see is changing **img.emoji** - you're telling me this stops render blocking?

Comment: Ok, I see that not always is loading the same content, I was talking about another style tag, screenshot  of the developer tools showing the CSS I was refering https://imgur.com/OEjBmj5

Comment: My guess is that they are doing some kind of A/B test, the content loaded is different randomly.

Comment: Yeah must be, and if its google page speed they're serving up the inline styles?

Comment: That I don't know, maybe, maybe is just a combination of luck and all the glory of several types of cache

Comment: I have a site where, thanks to mediaqueries, everything fits on single screen, whether desktop or mobile, with no scrolling. So there's no "fold". Insights treats as render-blocking a javascript needed to render the page.That script is external, but since all the other pages on the site use it, it's better in cache than slowing down the page speed. So there's no flexibility in pagespeed insights. (and of course, Google analytics is a no-no)

Answer (score 0):

The key to the Google PageSpeed insights is above-the-fold render blocking. If you check the site that you linked as your page speed test reference, there are no strictly inline styles - you are correct. However, they have a `<style>...</style>` block inside of their `<head>` that sets all of their most important styles for above-the-fold content. That means those styles render immediately, and all other supporting styles will load soon after - but your visitors (and Google PageSpeed) will not notice the difference.